# Should I wait for ajax request to load in vue or angular SSR?

Tags: angular, vue.js, server-side-rendering

I have application with vue or angular. when the app component load, I make an ajax request to get the data I display in the child components.

I also use server-side-rendering (ssr).

My question is should I include the ajax request for the data in the server side so everything include the data will be ready or for the data I need to do just a client ajax request?

Comment: Honestly, this is primarily opinion-based. It depends on the UX you want to provide, also is it a public website? If so do you want the data to be indexed by search engines?

Comment: Yes it public site. and I think I want the data to be index by the search engines. 
but I looking for knowledge about people who have experience in both ways (wait or not wait) and can tell if wait for the data is better or not by performance perspective.

Comment: There is no performance perspective, your backend will respond as quickly when called from the internet, than when called from local. And the amount of data will be almost the same in both cases (formatted in SSR, raw in client side)

Comment: I'll formulate an answer

Comment: It can take too long to ajax request to perform. so the request to the page will be slow. chrome lighthouse say my website will have lower score. no?

Comment: If you feel concerned about lightscore score, I know these kind of auditing tools don't like when there are many HTTP requests, but I don't know if they take the very first response time in account. In your case the overall loading time should be almost the same

Answer (score 1):

If you're talking about performance, the difference will not be significant.

Your backend will respond as quickly when called from the internet, than when called from local, and the amount of data will be almost the same in both cases (formatted in SSR, raw in client side).

So the things to take in consideration are the following:

- Which experience do you want for your users? Do you want to serve an empty app shell fast, then fill the blanks with data later? Or do you want a filled first paint of the app?
- If your app is public, and the concerned pages don't require authentication, do you want them to be indexed by search engines?

If you choose SSR, you'll have to deal with data loaded twice (once by the server, once by the client when the client side takes over). On Angular, there is the built-in [TransferHttpCacheModule](https://github.com/angular/universal/blob/master/docs/transfer-http.md) that serializes the raw data in HTML for use on client side. I presume there are also such things in Vue.